# Is there live performances of The Beatles playing "While my Guitar Gently Weeps"?

Tags: live-music, the-beatles

I love how the guitar sounds in The Beatles' song called *While My Guitar Gently Weeps*, at first I thought it was Harrison who played the guitar, but it turns out that **Eric Clapton was the one playing the guitar**, so I was looking for live videos of The Beatles playing this in a concert or something to see how they played it without Clapton, thing is that I found nothing.

Do you guys know where could I find a video like that, or why they didn't play that in concerts?

Comment: Look for the video of this song performed at the Rock & Roll Hall of Fame with Prince on lead.  He freaking SLAMS it.  People tend to forget, with his vocals and style and "popishness" that he's one heck of a great guitar player.

Answer (score 8):

As commonly known, The Beatles stopped touring and became a studio band in the later stages of their existence. The last tour they did was in 1966, and *While my Guitar Gently Weeps* was recorded in 1968.

In 1968 and 1969, they only [performed twice](http://www.setlist.fm/setlists/the-beatles-23d6a88b.html), none of the concerts featured the song. So, the song was never performed live at a concert by the band.

Answer (score 8):

No, the Beatles never performed it.

But George Harrison performed "While My Guitar Gently Weeps" together with Ringo Starr and Eric Clapton in his all-star [Concert for Bangladesh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Concert_for_Bangladesh) in August 1971.

The recording is available in the live album and the film made from the concert.

The video is here on YouTube:

https://youtu.be/A8CivPhu0fw

This is probably the first time that Harrison, Starr and Clapton performed this song together live.

Many musicians came and went on stage during these performances, but from looking at the video, it appears to me that for this song the bass player is Klaus Voormann, and the keyboard player is Leon Russell. Billy Preston is also listed as a performer on the concert.

[Wikipedia has a listing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/While_My_Guitar_Gently_Weeps#Performances) of Harrison's and Clapton's other notable live performances of "While My Guitar Gently Weeps".